# why g++ issue (and not issue) -Wreturn-type warnings

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, g++, compiler-warnings

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template <typename T> class MyClass {
public:
  // even not called, g() has -Wreturn-type warning
  double g() { std::cout << "g() called" << std::endl; }
  // only that f() is called, f() has -Wreturn-type warning otherwise, there is
  // no -Wreturn-type warning for it
  MyClass &f() { std::cout << "f() called" << std::endl; }
  // even not called and not instantiated, h() has -Wreturn-type warning
  // ! Interestingly, if i change return type from double to MyClass, there is
  // no -Wreturn-type warning if not called!!! Why? what the compiler is doing
  // under the hood?
  template <typename U> double h() {
    std::cout << "h() called" << sizeof(U) << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  MyClass<double> m;
  // if f() is not called, there will be no -Wreturn-type warning
  // m.f();

  (void)m;
}
```

When I compile using following command:

```
g++ -Wall -O3 -g app.cpp
```

the compiler issues:

```
app.cpp: In member function ‘double MyClass<T>::g()’:
app.cpp:10:56: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
   double g() { std::cout << "g() called" << std::endl; }
                                                        ^
app.cpp: In member function ‘double MyClass<T>::h()’:
app.cpp:20:3: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
   }
```

In all my functions I do not return intentionally,
I do not use function `f()`, so compiler do not raise warning, might be optimized out, that's understandable; but I do not use `h()` either, why is there a warning for it?

More weird is that if I change return type of `h()` from `double` to `MyClass`, the warning is gone

So what does the compiler see these functions and how does it treat them during compiling?

[Godbolt demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3TPcEqhco)

Comment: why there is a warning? Because the function is declared to return `double` but it has no `return`. I dont understand what is unclear about that.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai That's not the unclear point, if I read the question right, but instead why there is **not** a warning when return type is reference to `MyClass`...

Comment: Ending function that returns something other than `void` is UB and compiler is not required to report it. So you should be grad that you are getting at least some warnings early.

Comment: Side note: About [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)…

Comment: I guess it's something about `MyClass` being template. [insert some random legalese about return types being dependent on template type or not]

Comment: For comparison: clang seems [not to issue any warnings at all](https://godbolt.org/z/o5j7dYxG4) (to be honest I'm a bit disappointed of...).

Comment: @Aconcagua That actually makes more sense. Clang doesn't see a need to instantiate any of f,g,h so it doesn't and therefore does not issue a warning. Why gcc only warns about g and h but not f is still a mystery to me, tough.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen seems to be right, [removing the template](https://godbolt.org/z/KhPPK115j) makes GCC issue warnings for all functions, clang at least for the non-template ones ;)

Comment: @Aconcagua And adding dependency on template type to the return type also removes the warning, even if return type is e.g. `std::vector<T>` and not `MyClass`: https://godbolt.org/z/o1bKqa48M. Looks like a design decision to not check for missing return type if it depends on template, but I can't think of a good explanation for such decision.

Comment: It's a QoI issue. If you are bothered by it, submit a bug report to the gcc bugzilla.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen "design decision to not check for missing return type if it depends on template", it's the most possible conclusion based on all the experiments results

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Suffices even just returning T ;) – might have to do with at a template not being able to decide if the return type can be constructed at all (maybe abstract?). Maybe GCC delays decision until being able to decide if a `T` is a valid return type at all (we cannot return abstract by value...) to be able to print a more precise error message? What ever the reason for the decision is, we're just speculating anyway, we'd have to ask GCC developers to really know ;)

Answer (score 2):

A **dependent** return type can (sometimes) be `void`:

```
template<class T>
struct X {
  std::conditional_t<sizeof(T)<17,void,int> f() {}
};
```

GCC is simply waiting to check for the warning until the type is known.  It’s “obviously” never `void` in your examples, but consider that the condition might be an arbitrary constexpr calculation.

Comment: what does "but consider that the condition might be an arbitrary constexpr calculation", mean?

Comment: @shan: One could write `std::conditional_t<fibonacci(T::magic_number)<ackermann(T::other_magic,3),void,int>` or similar to do arbitrary amounts of inscrutable arithmetic.